# in_app_purchase how to check validity of restored purchase

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

On startup I call restorePurchases() to get the previous bought subscriptions.

This works fine but I also get subscriptions which where canceled by the user before!
They have status PurchaseStatus.restored and pendingCompletePurchase is true even though I called completePurchase().

How do I know if the purchase is still valid and not canceled by the user?

```
Future<void> initializeProAccountPurchase(context) async {
    available = await IAPService.checkIAPAvailability();

    if (available) {
      await IAPService.restorePurchases().onError((error, stackTrace) =>
          {print("error restore"), print(error.userInfo)});
      await getProAccountDetails({'subs_item_purchase', 'pro_account'});
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using this in_app_purchase package for in app purchase?

Comment: yes, I'm using the flutter package

Comment: Okay what kind of purchase your using? I mean consumable, non consumable, re -new subscription or auto re-new subscription?

Comment: I'm using auto re-new subscription

Comment: sorry, for the late replay.
you can check package documentation they mentioned for auto re-new subscription each store using different approach so you need to user stand that flow first.
App store - https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/
Play store - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12154973?hl=en